How to resolve Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException
I am testing a REST API. When I run the test even for 5-10min with a rate of 2 RPS, I am getting 1 or 2 SocketException errors. Can I come to a conclusion that this has to be resolved only from JMeter side and not from the application side because this error appears even with such a low throughput (2 tps) and the test was run only for 7min.? The error I am getting is:
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Socket closed

I tried adding the below in the user.properties file:
httpclient4.retrycount=1
hc.parameters.file=hc.properties

and the below in hc.properties file:
http.connection.stalecheckBoolean=true

but the error is still coming. I use Throughput Shaping Timer with bzm-Concurrency Thread group with tstFeedback option having a min of 10 threads to max of 100 threads. Even if the test was run for more than  an hour with 16tps, this error comes up.

Have you restarted JMeter after making the changes in properties files? If not - do this because the changes are only picked up on next run of JMeter.
If the issue still present I can only suggest enabling Java debug logging for SSL/TLS connections, it can be done by adding the next line to system.properties file
javax.net.debug=all

once done you can inspect the output in terminal to see who initiated closing of the connection and what were the headers

Yes, I started Jmeter after amending the lines in the properties file
